# Stripe in a cordova app shows desktop version of the stripe form

Tags: ios, cordova, stripe-payments

With a cordova app and stripe the desktop version of the form loads.

Loading it directly in ios safari works OK.
expecting:

[image: expected]

received:

[image: received]

Comment: Stripe does not support Cordova apps for Checkout. While you can make it work I would highly recommend moving off of Checkout and using Elements to build your own form instead.

Comment: I agree, though the time saved is probably worth the risk of Stripe changing the code underneath!  Using code push, so if they do change it, we dont need to wait for apple to re-review.  Plan to redo it when time is less restricted, and or app more successful!

Answer (score 0):

Found a nasty hack to get around it:

Call this before calling StripeCheckout.configure

```
StripeCheckout.__app.setForceView('IframeView');
StripeCheckout.__app.setForceManhattan(true);
```